# Connect to specific service instance using ServiceProxy.Create

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a public ASP.NET Core service with 5 instances, one on each service fabric cluster node. I also have a worker service with just one instance, the primary because this is a stateful service. I want to make a call from the worker service to a specific instance of the frontend.

I am using the following standard code to create a connection...

```
IFrontend c = ServiceProxy.Create<IFrontend>(new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/FrontendService"));
```

This works but will connect to one of the 5 ASP.NET Core services and it could be any of them. I want to connect to a specific one. Is there some specific format where you can provide the service instance identifier?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Clients connect using a WebSocket to a random ASP.NET Core frontend via a load balancer. That works fine. To send a message from the backend to a specific the client we need to get a message from the backend to the correct ASP.NET Core instance that has the WebSocket. I can send a message from the ASP.NET Core service to the backend to register the WebSocket is present. But not sure what info to provide so the backend can later on send a message back to the exact ASP.NET Core that has the WebSocket.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight solution for this. One thing I can think of is to have the ASP.NET Core service send a message to the backend to register the WebSocket is present, and have that message include the node name the frontend service is running on (via `ServiceContext.NodeContext.NodeName`).

Then have a pub/sub mechanism to send send a message (including the node name of the designated ASP.NET Core service instance you want to address) from the backend to all ASP.NET Core service instance and let only the ASP.NET Core service instance handle the message if the node names match.

You could use [this project](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors) for that

References:
[Call a specific instance of a service in Azure Service Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532285/call-a-specific-instance-of-a-service-in-azure-service-fabric)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7cc7df3-9872-4000-8cc6-c48cb47b0b3f/calling-all-stateless-service-instances-via-serviceproxy?forum=AzureServiceFabric

Answer (score 1):

As PeterBons mentioned, there is no straight solution for this kind of problem, there are many catches to be aware before you decide on any approach related to your initial plan, I can point a few, maybe will  help you make a better decision:

- There is no guarantee that the user is connected to FE1 when the response comes back, even though you keep a connection open, the connection might fail, and the user might connect to FE2 when it happens, your response will be redirected to the wrong server.
- The user might be still connected to same node on reconnection, but the original service might be moved around, is common on SF that services move around the nodes in case of failures or Load balancing, in this scenario, the connection might drop and reconnect on same node, if you keep track of the partition, the partition might be already on another node, receiving an useless message.
- The Worker response might fail when sending the message to FE1 and you will need to handle retries in the Worker, the same can happen if FE to the User fail, you also have to add a retry logic in there, increasing the complexity.

Some approaches that might work:

- Make the communication asynchronous using a message bus in the middle, so that both services does not care about each other state, every response sent from Worker to FE will be asynchronous, any failure might be handled on their time independently. You might want to use:

  - One Message Queue per partition or
  - A single Pub/Sub Topic to all partitions and each one handle what is forwarded to then.
- Or, can use a PaaS service that manages that for you, like [Azure SignalR Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/), in this case you need only to have an unique identification for the client and the worker keep it to send an answer back.